# Protecting PHPmyadmin in Ubuntu-Nginx-https environment without URL change or tmux

Tags: ubuntu, security, php, nginx, webserver

My current ways to protect PHPmyadmin (PMA) particularly form Brute Force Attacks (BFAs) in my `ubuntu-nginx-https` environment, are one or more of these:

**1)** Changing the location of the PMA directory to something wired and hard to guess.

**2)** Login from a permanent IP.

**3)** Login through a recognized VPN (<sub>this is an edit due to comments below</sub>).

**4)** Running PMA temporarily in a separate `tmux` session:

```
cat <<-"PHPMYADMIN" > /opt/pma.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    find /var/www/html -iname '*phpmyadmin*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
    cd /var/www/html && wget https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.zip
    find /var/www/html -type f -iname '*phpmyadmin*.zip' -exec unzip {} \;
    find /var/www/html -type d -iname 'phpmyadmin-*' -exec mv {} phpmyadmin \;

    sleep 2h

    find /var/www/html -iname '*phpmyadmin*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
    tmux kill-session
PHPMYADMIN
chmod +x /opt/pma.sh

cat <<-"BASHRC" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
    alias pma="tmux new-session -d 'bash /opt/pma.sh'"
BASHRC
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

then:

```
pma # execute script and use pma for 2 hours.
```

### Why I'm not comfortable using these ways

1. What if someone finds the wired unintuitive PMA path it could still try to brute force it.
2. I cannot afford that. I might move between apartments sometimes.
3. This might be a nice option though might be overwhelming for that purpose (I don't have other VPN uses at this era).
4. This script is quite heavy and lengthens the already very long Nginx Server Environment Setup (NSES) script I use.

### My question

What else do I have left to protect PMA from Brute force attack in my `ubuntu-nginx-https` environment?

Comment: You can always create a PHP-myadmin entry that is only accessible from your internal network or via VPN or if you really need that bad in the Internet at large, do user authentication via a X.509 certificate. (user auth mind you)

Comment: I've edited to include that I cannot use a permanent IP. Only a VPN or the x.509 certificates remain I guess.

Comment: What about some Apache `mod_security` equivalent for Nginx?

Comment: You can also restrict the IPs that access that page or put another layer the authentication on top. It works, they are not my favourite solutions.

Comment: 1. Did you mean to restrict PMA to a specific VPN? 2. `Another layer of authentication on top` like the x.509 certificate or you meant something else?

Comment: I've edited the question. An answer will be most welcome.

Comment: There are several ways of doing what you want. Ultimately, it is your decision. The question is borderline out-of-topic as "primarily opinion based", the edits may sway it on other side. You can always use dyndns if you have a public IP from an ISP operator.

Comment: Sounds expansive for a financially troubled guy like me...

Comment: https://freedns.afraid.org, not cost for 3 or 5 IPs or names cannot remember. see let´s encrypt also. https://letsencrypt.org

Comment: If I understand correct it's either to use a VPN, a permanent IP (free or purchased) / or authentication with a `X.509` certificate. WOW, the fact the PMA developers didn't include, and doesn't want to include a BFA defense mechanism is quite sad to me at the moment.

Comment: There are layers of authentication. Personally it is a very bad idea to expose a DB in the Internet at large by PHPMyAdmin. Mind you X.509 for site validation and X.509 for user auth are two different things.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mtigas/952344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has a section about "[Securing your phpMyAdmin installation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#securing-your-phpmyadmin-installation)" to which you should refer for more details.

My favorites:

1. Changing to a not obvious directory name is a simple way to greatly reduce brute-force attacks. Attackers have a variety of them they try, from /phpmyadmin/ to /phpMyAdmin-4.7.7/ and so on, but if you pick something that makes sense for you but isn't obvious for a bot to try, you'll be really reduce your attack vector.
2. Using the authentication logging that will be part of phpMyAdmin 4.8.0 (* see footnote), you can let specialized tools like Fail2Ban do the detection and blocking.
3. You can enable [two-factor authentication](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/two_factor.html#fa), starting with phpMyAdmin 4.8.0 *.
4. Using a Captcha can greatly reduce the effectiveness of a brute-force attack. See [this](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_CaptchaLoginPublicKey) and [this](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_CaptchaLoginPrivateKey) for the configuration directives.

* 4.8.0 isn't yet released as of when I'm writing this, but the development snapshots are generally pretty stable.